# How to stop ethernet interface in bridge configuration from obtaining IP address via DHCP

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp, ethernet

I'm trying to configure openvpn in bridging configuration. First step of doing this requires creating bridge interface (br0), bridging together physical ethernet interface (eth0) and logical tap0 interface. This can be done with simple script but I want to use less popular approach, configuring  bridge interface entirely via /etc/network/interfaces file (on Debian linux).

So I have removed all eth0 definitions form  /etc/network/interfaces and replaced if with following br0 definition:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
pre-up  openvpn --mktun --dev tap0
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
bridge_ports eth0 tap0
post-down openvpn --rmtun --dev tap0
```

This works as I expected, but there is only one problem: interface  eth0 is part of bridge interface br0 **AND** it also receive it's own IP address from my DHCP server (located on same LAN where eth0 is connected).

My questions is: how to stop eth0 interface from obtaining it's  own IP address? (It should only be part of br0 bridge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line `iface eth0 inet manual` to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.  This will tell network manager to ignore the eth0 file.

(Edited to include missing "inet".)

Comment: Thank you, it helped! (but line should be "iface eth0 inet manual" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work on Debian 11! enp2s0 kept taking DHCP address all the time. Finally I can propose working solution...

The reason configuration above fails is unknown to me, but I suppose it is related to dhcpcd server.

Let me first show my network setup.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet manual
    pre-up   ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down

allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet manual
    pre-up   ifconfig $IFACE up
    pre-down ifconfig $IFACE down

# The bridging interface br0
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
```

Now this is my complicated /etc/network/interfaces.d/br0 file:

```
# I want dhcp from corporate network, static IPv4 for accessing some hardware near me and IPv6 address on the bridge

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enp3s0 enp2s0
    bridge_stp off # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
    bridge_waitport 0 # no delay before port available
    bridge_brdigeprio 0
    bridge_fd 0 # no forward delay
    pre-up ip addr flush dev enp3s0
    pre-up ip addr flush dev enp2s0

# some numbers were replaced by X, so do not copy!
iface br0 inet6 static
    address fd01:XXXX:2015:XXXX:def4:12ff:XXXX:XXXX
    netmask 48

iface br0 inet static 
    address 192.168.8.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.254
    metric 250
```

And finally open your /etc/dhcpcd.conf Look for denyinterfaces and change accordingly your pattern (mine is below):

```
denyinterfaces enp*
```

I suppose in most cases it is enough to disable enp* interfaces, but someone might want to have a complicated setup as mine which works for more than year on my Debian.

jorio